# Throw drools validation if Regex doesn't match

Tags: regex, drools

```
        rule "doesnot match REGEX"
      when
           RuleActivator( targetMessage == "message" )
           $g: Parent(name matches "^[0-9]{4}[" "][A-Z]{2}[" "][0-9]{5}[" "]")
      then
           insert(new ValidationError(Validation($ROOT, $g, "name"), "SSDN"));
     end
```

Currently this rule will be throw error when the regex will be matched. I want to throw error when this Regex doesnot match.
So, is there any method in drools for it. Or there is some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`not matches`](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html/ch05.html):

> The operator **`not matches`**:
>
> The operator returns true if the String does not match the regular expression. The same rules apply as for the `matches` operator.

Judging by the requirements:

> Position 1-4: numeric part of postal code - Position 5: blanc - Position 6-7: two uppercases (A2) - Position 8: blanc - Position 9-13: address (numeric, align to the left, to be filled up with spaces) - Position 14: blanc

Your regex should look like the following one:

```
^[0-9]{4}[ ][A-Z]{2}[ ][0-9]{5}[ ]
```

Comment: I didn't understand.here my requirement was 
-    Position 1-4: numeric part of postal code
-    Position 5: blanc
-    Position 6-7: two uppercases (A2)

-    Position 8: blanc
-    Position 9-13: address (numeric, align to the left, to be filled up with spaces)
-    Position 14: blanc
-    Position 15-35: free text
So, I had written " " where I needed free space like for 5th position

Comment: I updated the regex. You do not need the double quote inside the character class.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked completely fine for me. Can u plz also suggest for how to restrict user till max 35 characters he can enter anything(even special characters) after the 14th character.

Comment: It is very easy, use a `[\\s\\S]` construct or `.` with `(?s)` inline modifier and a limiting quantifier with the `$` end of line/string anchor: `(?s)^[0-9]{4}[ ][A-Z]{2}[ ][0-9]{5}[ ].{0,35}$`, or `^[0-9]{4}[ ][A-Z]{2}[ ][0-9]{5}[ ][\\s\\S]{0,35}$`. The `{0,35}` limiting quantifier means *match 0 to 35 characters matching the preceding subpattern*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me so much. You really saved my lot of time. Plz suggest any best online tutorial for regex where I can also get knowledge like you. I was looking at W3schools but it wasn't that helpful. Again Thank you very muchhhh

Comment: I do not know your level of regex knowledge :) so that I can only suggest doing all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), reading through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean).

Comment: There is no need to use `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end of a regular expression since `matches` calls  Matcher.matches, which tries to match the entire string anyway. -- I feel that unnecessarily enclosing a single character in `[` and `]` does not improve readability, but you may feel different.

Comment: The `^` and `$` are not necessary with `matches`, it is true. As for `[ ]`, this is just an extra safety measure in case a verbose modifier is used.